Minimum weight maximum matching in the unit interval
Let $X$ and $Y$ denote two sets of $m$ and $n$ points distributed uniformly at random in the unit interval. When $m$ and $n$ are both large, is there a bound for the expected cost of a minimum-weight maximum bipartite matching between them? The case $m=n$ (in which case we get a perfect matching) is well-studied and the cost is proportional to $\sqrt{n}$, and is easily bounded as such by looking at differences of order statistics.

Do you want unit interval or unit square?

@SandeepSilwal Unit interval.  The unit square apparently looks more like $\sqrt{n \log n}$.
